# Why doesnt my image show up in my div thats inside another div?

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to get a image to show up in my div with the class of `itemImage` but for some reason it doesnt want to show up, I think this is a scaling issue because if I remove the image url and put `green` there instead it works.
Why is it doing this and is it possible to get it working with other images? So that they scale properly?

```css
.headSlot{
    background: url("https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/2007scape/images/3/35/Head_slot.png/revision/latest?cb=20130227123039");
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 25%;
}

.itemImage{
    background: url("https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/2007scape/images/b/b6/Adamant_full_helm.png/revision/latest?cb=20160809175941");
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="trigger">
                <div class="headSlot">
                    <div class="itemImage">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
```

Comment: You've answered your own question. Add `background-size: 100%` to the `itemImage` styles too.

Comment: @fubar Then this happends https://i.imgur.com/0ulkakP.png

Comment: Yep. That's because the two elements on which you're applying a background image overlap one another.

Comment: So what you commented didnt really answer the question :P

Comment: No, what I commented did answer the question. The image now shows up. The fact they're overlapping is another, different problem with your code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p0e8vcqo/ This one seems to work fine, different code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `background-size: contain` to `.itemImage` to make it scale correctly. Essentially, this contains the background image to the dimensions of the element.

**EDIT** For not only showing the image, but to also have it properly formatted.

```
.itemImage {
   background-size: contain;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Oh I see the problem here, I thought that was the intended picture. Updated with code that should properly display image.

Comment: @StevenTang Ahh I see the issue, great answer! Would +1 this twice if it was possible!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the trick

```css
.headSlot{
    background: url("https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/2007scape/images/3/35/Head_slot.png/revision/latest?cb=20130227123039");
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 25%;
}

.itemImage{
    background: url(https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/2007scape/images/b/b6/Adamant_full_helm.png/revision/latest?cb=20160809175941);
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 28px;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="trigger">
                <div class="headSlot">
                    <div class="itemImage">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
```

You needed to make sure the `background-size` was small enough to fit in the div and then to make sure the background doesn't get repeated. Finally, to center the background image relative to the div.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thanks for clearing the issue up! I feel like I now have a much better understanding of where the issue lays! +1